# Convert Stream<List<T>> to Stream<Map<K,T>>

Tags: dart, rxdart

I have a requirement of converting `Stream<List<T>>` to `Stream<Map<K,T>>`

I have a class

```
class Order
{
    int id;
    DateTime date;
}
```

I want to convert `Stream<List<Order>>` to `Stream<Map<DateTime, List<Order>>`

I want to display orders as below

### 12-Dec-2020

```
         Order 1
         Order 2
```

---

### 13-Dec-2020

```
         Order 3
         Order 4
```

---

### 14-Dec-2020

```
         Order 5
         Order 6
```

---

Suggestions for a better DS are welcome.

How do I do this?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There might be multiple orders for a date. Therefore Stream<Map<DateTime, List<Order>>

Comment: I have a requirement to display orders grouped by date. Suggestions are welcome for a better DS

Answer (score 1):

Using [`groupListsBy`](https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/blob/9967dcd3d7645db6de48d5abfab3018bb0c84236/lib/src/iterable_extensions.dart#L389) from `collection: ^1.15.0`

```dart
K keySelector(T t) { ... }

final Stream<List<T>> source$ = ...;
final Stream<Map<K, List<T>>> result$ = source$.map((list) => list.groupListsBy(keySelector));
```

Comment: The needed import: `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Comment: Something is off! I'd like to group the lists by their first number. So `int keySelector(List<int> l) { return l[0]; }`. `source$.map((list) => list.groupListsBy(keySelector));` tells me `The argument type 'int Function(List<int>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(int)'.`. What em I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any package.

First, you have to create an empty `Map`, then map a `List<Order>` to a map with a key as a date from the list item (single order) then add it to That Empty map.

Check if the date is available as a key in Map. If the date exists as a key in that map then simply add a new order to that value or else simply add a new key to the Map.

**Code:**

```dart
Stream<List<Order>> orders = ...;

Stream<Map<DateTime, List<Order>>> ordersByDate = {};

orders.forEach((Order order){
    ordersByDate.keys.contains(order.date)
      ? ordersByDate.update(order.date, (oldValue) => oldValue + <Order>[order])
      : ordersByDate[order.date] = [order];
});


print(ordersByDate);

//At here your ordersByDate
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Fold method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) is what you're looking for.
Example:

```dart
void main() async {
  final today = DateTime.now();
  final tomorrow = today.add(const Duration(days: 1));
  final order1 = Order(1, today);
  final order2 = Order(2, today);
  final order3 = Order(3, tomorrow);
  
  final x = await Stream
    .fromIterable([order1, order2, order3])
    .fold<Map<DateTime, List<Order>>>({}, (val, element)  {
      (val[element.date] ??= []).add(element);
      
      // Same as:
      // if (val[element.date] == null) {
      //   val[element.date] = [];
      // }
      // val[element.date]!.add(element);
    
      return val;
    });
  
  print(x);
}


class Order
{
    int id;
    DateTime date;
  
    Order(this.id, this.date);
  
    @override
    String toString() {
      return 'Order(id: $id, date: $date)';
    }
}
```